# Difference between 2 questions on the alternating group $A_{4}$.

Tags: representation-theory

I have to answer 2 questions on the alternating group $A_{4}$:

One of them asks me to find all irreducible complex representations of the group $A_{4}$ (and calculate their characters) while the other one asks me to find all 1-dimensional representations of $A_{4}$. I have answered the second question without  using the character table. but I feel like the answer of the first question like the second one, could anyone explain the difference for me please?

Thank you!

Comment: I mean, yes, if you know all irreducible representations of $A_4$ then you certainly know the $1$-dimensional representations. Presumably if you do the first question first, then the second requires more work.

Comment: For those of us following from the peanut gallery who haven't had algebra in decades, would someone mind linking to a definition of, or explaining what is meant by, representations of a group?  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertShore Of course. Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups).

Comment: @DietrichBurde So it's an action of a group on a vector space that respects vector addition and scalar multiplication, which makes it a homomorphism into the group of automorphisms of the vector space?  Thanks very much.

Comment: If you have a character table of $S_4$ at hand you may want to check what happens when you restrict those to $A_4$. Indeed, the second exercise can be done without the first, and it may be more natural to do that first.